# error using tty.usbserial-xxxx: could not open, resource busy

Tags: macos, usb, catalina, error, driver

Since one year I'm using a MacBook Pro 13 upgraded to Catalina in October. I use the Mac to program same embedded module via RS232 (different adapters with different chips, e.g. FTDI) and it is still working.

Last Monday I changed to a new MacBookPro 16. I used a backup and all worked proper, but I can't connect to any USB-to-Serial adapters. I got the same

> error [16] could not open port /dev/tty.usbserial-xxxx: Resource busy ...

I tried to reinstall all corresponding drivers, but without success.

Comment: When you say you reinstall and have no success are you asking for help to find the installer logs so you can see what failure was logged?

Comment: Yeah, that could be the first step.

In the meantime, I passed the USB port to a virtual machine, where I could access it without any problems, but not under macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Troubleshooting CH340G issues on macOS](https://community.platformio.org/t/troubleshooting-ch340g-issues-on-macos/9522) it could be a conflict between drivers *eg.* Apple's `com.apple.DriverKit-AppleUSBCHCOM.dext` and a third-party `usbserial.kext`. Disabling and removing drivers might help. I just restored access to `/dev/tty.usbserial-1410` for an old LOLIN32 Lite ESP32 module by unplugging it and running:

```bash
sudo kextunload /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext/
```

You can plug it back in after the first line to see if it helped. If so, proceed. If not, don't.